# How can I use objects in an ArrayList to be able to add or remove them from other bit of storage Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to be able to create a set of inventories which are able to store objects that I choose. I have an `ArrayList` of the objects I need to be able to store in these inventories which have an "item number", "description" and "price".
My question is, what can I use to create these inventories so the user is able to add or remove items (which all come from the `ArrayList` of items) into them. The only way I can think it would work is by creating another `ArrayList` being the inventories but I wouldn't know how to add/remove the objects to them seeing as they're in the `ArrayList`

I have a main method which is where my `ArrayList` is and an item class with a constructor, getters, setters and `toString`.

Comment: ArrayLists don't store objects; neither do variables or fields. They store references (and variables/fields can also store primitives).

Comment: Could you explain your question a little more, specifically the part about not knowing how to add/remove objects as they're is the ArrayList. May be take an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add or remove class objects in `ArrayList`. Following is an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class InventoryHandler {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Inventory inv1 = new Inventory(1,"item1",10.1);
       Inventory inv2 = new Inventory(2,"item2",20.1);
       Inventory inv3 = new Inventory(3,"item3",30.1);

       ArrayList<Inventory> invs = new ArrayList<Inventory>();
       //Adding objects
       invs.add(inv1);
       invs.add(inv2);
       invs.add(inv3);

       System.out.println("After adding objects");
       for(Inventory inv: invs) {
          System.out.println("Item: "+inv.getItemNumber()+" Desc: "+
                              inv.getItemDescription()+" Price: "+inv.getItemPrice());

       }

       //Removing objects
       invs.remove(inv2);

       System.out.println("After removing a object");
       for(Inventory inv: invs) {
          System.out.println("Item: "+inv.getItemNumber()+" Desc: "+
                              inv.getItemDescription()+" Price: "+inv.getItemPrice());

       }
   }
}


class Inventory {
   private int itemNumber;
   private String itemDescription;
   private double itemPrice;

   public Inventory(int itemNumber, String itemDescription, double itemPrice) {
      this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
      this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
      this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
   }

   public int getItemNumber() {
      return this.itemNumber; 
   }

   public String getItemDescription() {
      return this.itemDescription;
   }

   public double getItemPrice() {
      return this.itemPrice;
   }

   public void setItemNumber(int newItemNumber) {
      this.itemNumber = newItemNumber;
   }

   public void setItemDescription(String newItemDescription) {
      this.itemDescription = newItemDescription;
   }

   public void setItemPrice(double newItemPrice) {
      this.itemPrice = newItemPrice;
   } 
}
```